# Deserializar JSON con el siguiente formato [param 1, param 2,param 3]

Tags: c#, json

Como puedo deserializar esta información.

```
{"games":"[
[ID, Descripcion1, Descripcion2, Descripcion3],
[222, Halo,      $2333, null],
[333, Sugar,    $333, null]]}
"
```

Comment: If this question is in English, please post to the original StackOverflow site. To have it discussed here, please post your question in Spanish only. — Si la pregunta está en inglés, por favor pregúntala en el sitio original de StackOverflow. Para tratarla aquí, por favor pregunta únicamente en español.

Comment: Gracias ya se encuentra en español

Comment: intentas algo hasta ahora?? por favor mira el [tour] y tambien [ask]

Comment: De momento ademas ese json no valida...

Answer (score 0):

no puedes porque esta mal formado, en varios aspectos, uno de ellos es que te sobran unas comillas justo despues de `"games":`

```
{
  "games":
    "[
        [ID, Descripcion1, Descripcion2, Descripcion3],
        [
          222, Halo,$2333, null
        ],
        [
          333, Sugar, $333, null]
     ]
}
```

Una vez lo soluciones de todas formas hay más por hacer, ya que ese objeto no es un objeto JSON valido. 
Deberías exponerlo así

```
{
    "games": [
        {
            "Id": "222",
            "Descripcion1": "Halo",
            "Descripcion2": "$2333",
            "Descripcion3": null
        },
        {
            "Id": "333",
            "Descripcion1": "Sugar",
            "Descripcion2": "$333",
            "Descripcion3": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Y estando así podrías deserializarlo en objetos de estas clases

```
public class Game
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion1 { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion2 { get; set; }
    public object Descripcion3 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Game> games { get; set; }
}
```

Haciendo uso de [Newtonsoft JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

```
RootObject g = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```